# Response.data returning json data as string Laravel 8/Axios

Tags: php, laravel, axios

In my laravel controller i'm returning a response as below

```
return response()->json([
                'name' => 'Abigail',
                'state' => 'CA',
            ], 400);
```

When i make a call from a browser using Axios the data I get back is showing the json object as a string

[image]

doing json.parse(response.data) also returns `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0`

I'm using Laravel 8

the content-type is application/json and so is accept.
Is there something that needs to be included?

For the Axios call i have a class called User which contains this static login method [image]

The login method is then called inside another file
[image]

Comment: Show the code of `axios` from which where you are trying to get the response.

Comment: Hi, I have added a screenshot of the axios call.

Comment: Ok, now what is the result of `console.log(response);`  in `login` function ??

Comment: The second image above is the result of the console log. It comes back as expected except the response.data is a string

Comment: Ok, then check only using `response.status` and if you want to get any params from response then use it like: `response.data.name` and `response.data.state`

Comment: That’s the problem because response.data is showing up as a string, name and state is inaccessible. What I’m trying to achieve is to get response.data to show up as an object. I have tried parsing and stringifying it but none works. Not sure why quotes are getting added to response.data value

Comment: Any facade you used for `response()` in laravel?

Comment: No. I just tried this on Postman and it seems to be showing response.data as an object i'm only getting the issue when i'm using a browser.

Comment: Ok, that's means that the problem is from frontend, not from laravel.

Comment: Try using this way: `axios.post('/api/event/item', {
    event_id: eventId,
    item_id: itemId,
    description: description
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });`

Comment: Just tried that and getting the same issues above. I think i may have found a way around it. If you look at the second image above you will see that data contains a space before the object value begins. If I use trim() then JSON.parse it i'm able to access the object values.  This would work for now but It would be nice to get it coming back as it's original object type instead of string

Comment: Ok, nice. Good one.

Comment: I don't think it's a space. If you open your browser console and enter `JSON.parse(' {"name": "Abigail"}')`, it'll work fine. What do you get for `console.log(response.data.charCodeAt(0))`?

Comment: console.log(response.data.charCodeAt(0)) returns 160

Answer (score 0):

use

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

to convert it to JavaScript object.

Also I think your return statement inside the controller adds some spaces at the beginning of the json string. Try below code to make sure you remove any possible space additions:

```
return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail','state' => 'CA'], 400);
```

Comment: JSON.parse returns an error. Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0

Comment: could you please show the whole error message?

Comment: Hi, If you are talking about the Json.parse error then that’s the whole error

Comment: I rectified my answer. be sure to check it out

Comment: Thanks but it seems that’s not the issue. Response is still coming back as a string.